# nginx default to php if node not available?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I want to default to a php application if the node applications are not currently responding to requests. (i.e. down).

What do I do?

Below is my nginx config

```
upstream my_servers {
    least_conn;
    #ip_hash;                    # ensures persistence of session id across servers
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;     # httpServer2 listens to port 8001
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;    # httpServer1 listens to port 8000
    server 127.0.0.1:80; <---- THIS ONE IS THE PHP APP

    #this could also be entirely a different host server
    #Ex. server 113.333.123.190:8000;
}



server {
    listen 80;
    server_name weburl.com;

    root /home/vince/Documents/weburl/static_php_player;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to list my nodejs config section

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name weburl.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        #tell Nginx to distribute the load
        proxy_pass http://my_servers/;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Add the backup option to the php server, otherwise all the petitions will be handled by the 3 servers

```
upstream my_servers {
    least_conn;
    #ip_hash;                    # ensures persistence of session id across servers
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;     # httpServer2 listens to port 8001
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;    # httpServer1 listens to port 8000
    server 127.0.0.1:80  backup; <---- THIS ONE IS THE PHP APP
```